# Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-router-dom'. heroku, en produccion

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

tengo una app escrita n react y estoy usando react-router-dom para las rutas, en desarrolo la app and bien, no tengo ningun problema, pero cuando hice el deploy en haroku me aparece este error

```
/app/src/App.tsx
TypeScript error in /app/src/App.tsx(3,39):
  Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-router-dom'. '/app/node_modules/react-router- 
  dom/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm i --save-dev @types/react-router-dom` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file 
  containing `declare module 'react-router-dom';`  TS7016

  1 | import { FC } from "react";
  2 | //react-router-dom
> 3 | import { BrowserRouter, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
    |                                       ^
  4 | //routers
  5 | import Route from "./routers";
  6 | const App: FC = () => {
```

instale el `@type` del modulo pero aun asi sigo teniendo el mismo problema, lo instalo como dependencia y como dependencia de desarrollo pero me sigue dando el mismo error, no se que pasa

Comment: Tratar `npm i --save-dev @types/react-router-dom`

Comment: ya lo instale de esa manera pero me sigue dando el mismo error

Comment: Encontré esto en Google: mueva todas las `devDependencies` a `dependencias` en `package.json` y vuelva a intentarlo. Es una mala idea, así que ten cuidado.

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que estás utilizando Typescript; si esto es correcto, podrías probar con los siguiente:

> npm install @types/react-router-dom -D

O si estás utilizando Yarn:

> yarn add @types/react-router-dom -D

Espero que te sea de utilidad!